# Java Date vs Gregorian Calendar / 48h difference?

Tags: java, calendar

I had a curious situation at work, where an application sent us XML containing the value "0001-01-01", which was parsed into an instance of `XmlGregorianCalendar`. I then realized, the value magically converted into "0001-01-03", the exact amount of 2 days was added.

This happened during the conversion from `GregorianCalendar` to Date, which I reproduced as followed:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
        final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        GregorianCalendar gregCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        gregCalendar.setTime(dateFormat.parse("0001-01-01"));
        XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregCalendar);

        System.out.println("calendar: " + calendar);
        System.out.println("date: " + calendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> calendar: 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
> date: Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 GMT 1

The milliseconds differ by the exact amount of 172800000. Does anybody know why?

Comment: I added a sample output which was what I got when I ran it. Feel free to edit it if what you're seeing is different.

Comment: People WILL be seeing different things because of their timezones. Your zone is GMT so you see the output seen in the question. I am in EST so I get this output: calendar: 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
date: Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 EST 1

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479

Comment: @jontro: This one isn't due to time zone differences.

Comment: Note: this date only exists retrospectively.  At the time, the year was different as it wasn't based on Jesus. March 25th was new year day, with March being the first month (btw Sept = 7, Oct = 8, Dec = 10)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Indeed. The term *proleptic* is used to describe the extrapolation of the Gregorian calendar backwards, including all its leap year shenanigans. Interestingly it's why the UK tax year starts on April 6th. Nice of you to remind us of the etymology of Sept, Oct, Nov, and Dec!

Comment: @Bathsheba An obscure one for you; christian religious festivals which occur between Feb 25th and 28th are one day later in a leap year. i.e. the day added is Feb 25th, not Feb 29th, tracing back to the 25th being the first day of the year.

Comment: @PeterLawrey As an organist I should have known that, but didn't!

Comment: @Bathsheba correction it's Feb 24th not 25th ;) https://www.comedy.co.uk/tv/qi/episodes/12/13/

Comment: could someone give me a working example, as i'm not able to reproduce it with a calendar->date conversion falling to the 1st. I always get the 3rd, no matter if i use MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE or the real 0001-01-01 as GregorianChange Date.

Answer (score 6):

Cute isn't it? The Java `GregorianCalendar` is **not** a proleptic Gregorian Calendar (despite its misleading name) **but** a *composite calendar* consisting of a Julian beginning and Gregorian end. (You can even set the cutover date yourself.)

In the Gregorian Calendar, January 1, 0001 is a Monday.

In the Julian Calendar, January 1, 0001 is a Saturday.

And there, my friends, is the difference of two days.

References:

https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1&country=22 
https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1&country=23
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

See `SetGregorianChange` in the final link in particular.

Comment: Can you explain why if I use the date 01/01/1582 my output is 1st Jan and 22nd December - a difference of 10 days?

Comment: Yup. The 10 days is due to most of Europe adopting the Gregorian Calendar in that year.

Comment: @Michael jfneis' answer gives all details about all those differences...

Comment: The link is the interesting thing... Read answers of that post.